# Sweave, how to suppress opening new instance of a pdf when running pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, pdf, emacs, auctex, sweave

Since I have setup SumatraPDF to automatically refresh PDFs when they change, how can I suppress "view" (resulting in opening a new instance of the pdf) when using the shortcut

`M-n P` (running pdfLaTeX) in Emacs with AucTeX installed.

Ideas?

Comment: I suspect this is linked to the editor you use: which one?

Comment: @JosephWright Emacs, problems are with auctex (it normally worked).

Comment: `M-n P` is not a defined shortcut on my version of AucTex. What command does that binding run for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-n P` calls `ess-swv-PDF` (which is part of the ESS package), which includes a hard-coded call to your pdfviewer. However, you can customize the viewer it will use, which is stored in the variable `ess-pdf-viewer-pref`. Setting this to a no-op, like ":", should effectively suppress the 'view' command.

`M-x customize-variable ess-pdf-viewer-pref <RET>` and set the value there.

Answer (score 0):

When `ess-swv-PDF` runs, it calls `ess-get-pdf-viewer`, which

"gets external PDF viewer to be used from ESS.  Use `ess-pdf-viewer-pref` when that is executably found by `M-x executable-find`.  ***Otherwise try a list of fixed known viewers.***"

In other words, even if the variable `ess-pdf-viewer-pref` is set to `nil`, a ***fixed known viewer*** is searched for.  Unfortunately this means the only way to prevent `ess-swv-PDF` from displaying the pdf is to redefine or modify the function.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Posts from new users are required by the system to be reviewed and possibly edited to help with any problems.

Comment: The documentation for `ess-get-pdf-viewer` is not correct. From the code in the ESS version I have, what actually happens is "Use ess-pdf-viewer-pref when set. Otherwise try a list of fixed known viewers". The `(executable-find ess-pdf-viewer-pref)` line has been removed. This is with ESS version 12.09-2.

Comment: It does still try the list of fixed known viewers though, so the solution to just set `ess-pdf-viewer-pref` won't stop a pdf viewer from being opened when you do a `M-n P`.  Your solution worked for the questioner because s/he was using SumatraPDF and doens't have one of the "fixed known viewers" installed.  I'm also using ESS version 12.09-2 and, for reference, that list of fixed known viewers is evince, kpdf, okular, xpdf, acroread, and xdg-open.